# How to count unique cells in a matrix while exluding errors and blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Gantt chart and I would like to count the number of unique cells that are not blank and not error values. This is an example of what my data looks like.

```
         308940   #NUM!    603460
827881   827881   827881   827881
         348490   #NUM!    887288
         #NUM!    #NUM!    602713
         888567   888567   888567
ABD532   ABD532   ABD532   ABD532
```

I have tried a few formulas but to no avail.

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF('Post Gantt'!H2:K7,'Post Gantt'!H2:K7))}
```

This formula counts everything but it does not exclude errors or blank cells. I also tried a formula with frequency match but that would return errors I think about the blank cells.

I would like the formula to achieve the following value for the example data set above.

```
8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(('Post Gantt'!H2:K7<>"")/(COUNTIFS('Post Gantt'!H2:K7,'Post Gantt'!H2:K7)+('Post Gantt'!H2:K7="")),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR(H2:K7&"","")<>"")/COUNTIF(H2:K7,H2:K7&""))
```

The `IFERROR` will get rid of errors, and then using the `&""` will prevent Excel from interpreting blank cells as `0`, and then `<>""` will ignore blanks.

**EDIT:** With the sheet names:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR('Post Gantt'!H2:K7&"","")<>"")/COUNTIF('Post Gantt'!H2:K7,'Post Gantt'!H2:K7&""))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!